# Unpacking multi-level python dictionary into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I have a multi-level dictionary as my input. The first level of the dictionary represents a coordinate (e.g. `x`, `y`, `angle_z`, ...). The second level represents all the possible values for that coordinate. The following level represents all the other coordinates whose value should change while the first coordinate is kept fixed, and so on.
The structure of an example dictionary is as follows:

#### Input dictionary

```py
dictionary = {
    'x': {
        1: {
            'y': {
                1: {'angle_z': 3},
                4: {'angle_z': 5}
            }
        },
        2: {
            'z': {
                3: {'angle_y': 2}
            }
        }
    },
    'z': {
        2: {'y': 10}
    }
}
```

I want a function (which I expect to be recursive) that unpacks this dictionary returning a list of dictionaries that represent all the combinations of coordinates, i.e. my output should be as follows:

#### Expected output

```py
[{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'angle_z': 3}, 
 {'x': 1, 'y': 4, 'angle_z': 5},
 {'x': 2, 'z': 3, 'angle_y': 2},
 {'z': 2, 'y': 10}]
```

Each coordinate can only appear once in a sequence of coordinates, i.e. the case `{'x':{1:{'x':2}}}` would not be acceptable. Apart from that, I'm looking for a function that is **as general as possible**, not dependent on the specific names of the coordinates (`x`, `y`, ...) and that can work with any number of layers in the dictionary.

Below is my current attempt which is far from what I want to achieve:

**My attempt**

```py
def unpack_dictionary(dictionary):
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        if len(dictionary) == 1:
            key = next(iter(dictionary))
            rest = dictionary[key]
            sub_results = unpack_dictionary(rest)
            return [{key: value, **sub_dict} for value in sub_results for sub_dict in sub_results]
        else:
            results = []
            for key, value in dictionary.items():
                sub_results = unpack_dictionary(value)
                for sub_dict in sub_results:
                    sub_dict[key] = value
                    results.append(sub_dict)
            return results
    else:
        return [{}]
```

Output:

```py
[{'y': {'angle_z': {}, 1: {'angle_z': 3}},
  'angle_z': {},
  1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
  'x': {1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
   2: {'z': {3: {'angle_y': 2}}}}},
 {'y': {'angle_z': {}, 1: {'angle_z': 3}},
  'angle_z': {},
  4: {'angle_z': 5},
  1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
  'x': {1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
   2: {'z': {3: {'angle_y': 2}}}}},
 {'y': {'angle_z': {}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}},
  'angle_z': {},
  1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
  'x': {1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
   2: {'z': {3: {'angle_y': 2}}}}},
 {'y': {'angle_z': {}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}},
  'angle_z': {},
  4: {'angle_z': 5},
  1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
  'x': {1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
   2: {'z': {3: {'angle_y': 2}}}}},
 {'z': {3: {'angle_y': {}}, 'angle_y': {}},
  3: {'angle_y': {}},
  'angle_y': {},
  2: {'z': {3: {'angle_y': 2}}},
  'x': {1: {'y': {1: {'angle_z': 3}, 4: {'angle_z': 5}}},
   2: {'z': {3: {'angle_y': 2}}}}},
 {2: {'y': {}}, 'y': {}, 'z': {2: {'y': 10}}}]
```

Comment: @ScottHunter, I added my current attempt. That syntax in your second comment is not valid for a dictionary, is it?

Comment: What if input dictionary was `{'x':{1:{'x':2}}}`?

Comment: Please be specific as to *how* your attempt "is far from what I want to achieve".

Comment: What I want to achieve is the expected output that I wrote in the question. If you use my current implementation on the example dictionary I think it is clear what I mean by "far from what I want to achieve"

Comment: @ScottHunter `{'x':{1:{'x':2}}}` would not be acceptable, the coordinate can only appear once in a specific sequence of coordinates

Comment: "... I'm looking for a function that is as general as possible..."

Comment: @ScottHunter I corrected my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
dictionary = { ... }
expect = [ ... ]

def unpack_dictionary(dictionary):
    paths = []
    def collect(d, path):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if not isinstance(v, dict):
                paths.append(path | {k: v})
            else:
                for path[k], f in v.items():
                    collect(f, path)
                    del path[k]
    collect(dictionary, {})
    return paths

result = unpack_dictionary(dictionary)

print(result)
print(result == expect)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZNNboMwEIUX3fkUswMkN2r-pAopJ4miCIFpLKixwKAklJN0k017qJ6mjG0CTtLOBgZ_4_dmjD-_5UkdCnG5fNUqfX79eYoSHiteiKg8wQZaAn14Ry-0rxjzaaLXT97tp4HzIvGWs_25B5YdvUNWLrLuHGLMJqWLO_XzQ_XluDXaW_y5NZkI3OyFWrq5-YvFSEfYUbJY9cPZtnowc2oGgE-nWyDgEiuHWKOmARbUKC-vgLGsgbMFrI8dIQlLoRYyirP9eFr--BqE2qyM1KFCnzudYlVc5Hlv3k-oXrUgRlqUkFFogAtIZlyx98qfLGPwFEShgFdcVCoSMfMbCqh6w121Z5GUTCQ-JvABbRZC0wUOy_KK3VejGSzaZjsKKVpqHlsaYugrtX09hBKWD7uSadE4OAqt9VcyVZfCtEFIyao6xyP_d-qEyJIL5Rs6cDLYbMD8OIG5afbCDRfvFw)):

```
[{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'angle_z': 3},
 {'x': 1, 'y': 4, 'angle_z': 5},
 {'x': 2, 'z': 3, 'angle_y': 2},
 {'z': 2, 'y': 10}]
True
```